# Why do i see multiple calls in fiddler when starting signalr connection

Tags: angular, signalr

I'm setting up a signalr connection from my angular front-end to a Asp.Net Core back-end. 
With fiddler i see multiple calls when starting the connection. The first call isn't completing which is a problem for our e2e tests.

I tried set SkipNegotiation: true, transport: SignalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets but then the connection can't be established anymore because of a missing Connection ID

```
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()                          
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .withUrl('/api/notificationHub', { 
                  // skipNegotiation: true, transport: 
                     signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                 }).build();
this.hubConnection.start().then((x) => {
  console.log(x);
  }).catch((x) => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

I expect all calls to complete. 
but the actual situation is that the first call doesn't complete (or it takes a very long time)

[image]

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/notificationHub?id=BHSyLOnn5BfBbaFYQ7qboQ
```

--Raw request of first call

GET http://localhost:4200/api/notificationHub?id=cm1MjKA22om6orpWoDcO3Q HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,nl-NL;q=0.7

--Raw request of second call

POST http://localhost:4200/api/notificationHub?id=BHSyLOnn5BfBbaFYQ7qboQ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 32
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Origin: http://localhost:4200
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,nl-NL;q=0.7

{"protocol":"json","version":1}

Comment: 1st one might be the OPTION call and 2nd be the actual call.

Comment: It looks like you are right, but I still don't understand why it doesnt give a response or is that normal for OPTION calls?

Comment: Have a read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) to more about `OPTION calls`

Answer (score 1):

MY problem is solved.
The first call was the handshake for the signalR connection. Which returned 101 switching protocol when running my front-end and back-end from visual studio. (Which uses ISS Express)

But when my back-end was hosted with ISS it didn't return 101. (It didn't return anything)

After turning on some extra logging on the signalR connection I found out that IIS Express was using websocket but that IIS didnt.

I had to install websockets in IIS to resolve my problem.

Thanks for the suggestions!